# sequelize dynamic construct where with Op.or javascript

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

```
const type = TYPE.get(type_name) || '[Op.or]: [{type: 1}, {type: 2}]';
await someTable.findAndCountAll({
        where: { user_id, type },
        attributes: [
          'title',
          ['description', 'desc'],
          ['createdAt', 'created'],
          ['updatedAt', 'last_modified'],
        ],
      });
```

So, I am trying to pass in type for the where condition.  If TYPE.get(type_name) returns a value, then use the value as type, otherwise use the Op.or operation to include both type 1 and 2.  However, the way I am trying to get it to work isn't working.  currently, if TYPE.get(type_name) returns a value, it works.  if it doesn't return a value, the where condition gets substitute into

```
type='[Op.or]: [{type: 1}, {type: 2}]'
```

which is not what I want.  Does anyone know how to get this done correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.  Need to do the following:

```
  const where = type
    ? { user_id, status: 1, type}
    : { user_id, status: 1, [Op.or]: [{ type: 1 }, { type: 2 }] };

await someTable.findAndCountAll({
        where: where,
        attributes: [
          'title',
          ['description', 'desc'],
          ['createdAt', 'created'],
          ['updatedAt', 'last_modified'],
        ],
      });
```